# Calling the viewWillAppear after the first time

Tags: objective-c, timer, xcode5, viewwillappear

I have a game that uses a timer. The user has 10 seconds to do something. I have a pause button in it and I am trying to set how much time is left in the viewWillDisappear and then set the label with how much time is left in the viewWillAppear. So that if there was 6 seconds left when the user paused, when they resumed, the viewWillAppear would be executed and the label would be at 6 seconds. But the problem is, the viewWillAppear is being executed when the user first starts that level, which completely messes up the time. Is there any way I could only execute the viewWillAppear after the first time? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. `viewWillAppear` is called every time when the view will appear. Naturally it is called before the first appearance too.

What yould you do? 
`viewDidLoad` is called only once. It is called before `viewWillAppear` will be called. You could initialize the iVar with the remaining time to 10s in `viewDidLoad`. Use the same iVar (or what ever you are using) as you would in `viewWillDisappear`. In the first appearance `viewWillAppear` will be called straight away so that re-setting the counter to the saved value of remaining time would not do any harm to your logic.

Comment: Apologies. It is short for instance variable. You must be using something anyway to store the remaining time, the 6 seconds in your example.

Comment: Okay this makes much more sense now! Thank you very much. I am going to try that out and get back to you